# Client proof public key encryption

Tags: .net, security, public-key, pgp, public-key-encryption

I want to set up an automated email of sensitive data to a non-techy client, and I'm looking for some very easy to use public key encryption (or rather decryption) desktop software I can supply them which will allow them to generate a password protected key pair, present the public key to them in a way which they can easily put in an email to me, and then offer a nice straightforward browse-select-decrypt function they can use on any downloaded attachment I send them. At my end I'd be hoping to use the likes of Bouncy Castle's PGP.

Does anyone have any recommendations? I've looked at GPG and SecureZip and neither appears straightforward and focused enough. The less the software does beyond generate and decrypt the better really, otherwise I'm going to be pushed towards using symmetric Winzip password protection.

Comment: What is the client's existing mail software? Will the sensitive data all come from one source, or from many? There are plugins (some free, some far from it) for most common mail clients ... but it doesn't get an awful lot easier than GPG.

Comment: Hi dajames. Following your comment I took a second look at GPG and found it was a bit more client friendly than I first thought, especially when using the GPA tool included in gpg4win. Could you please submit your suggestion as an answer so I may award you your just deserts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use commercial/opensource library (Which uses OpenPGP, or ZIP encryption, or whatever else), and write small utility, which will do the needed task for customer.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your budget and existing apps, you could use a standard PGP plugin for Microsoft Outlook which will offer very simple encrypt/decrypt integration by the addition of a simple button to the existing icons.

Lotus Notes also has a similar plugin, and there are a range of open source ones as well.

Using this route you minimise problems with user knowledge. If they are slightly more tech savvy, you can use various apps such as Windows Privacy Tray (which incorporates GPG and is free) but it does require a couple of simple steps to encrypt/decrypt/manage keys etc.